# Total Amount by Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

Below are two sample queries, how can I combine them to get a total by day?

So the expected result is for example:

09 Aug 2019 - $500

08 Aug 2019 - $400

```
select sum(Amount)
from 
(
select sum(Amount) as Amount from FactFinance FA
Inner Join DimDate DD on 
FA.DateKey = DD.DateKey
where DD.Date <= '09 Aug 2019'
group by OccKey
having sum(Amount) >0
) a

select sum(Amount)
from 
(
select sum(Amount) as Amount from FactFinance FA
Inner Join DimDate DD on 
FA.DateKey = DD.DateKey
where DD.Date <= '08 Aug 2019'
group by OccKey
having sum(Amount) >0
) a
```

Comment: Share a sample data and the expected results, as _formatted text_ please not images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution using a sub-select to get the `SUM`:

```
SELECT DD.Date, (
  SELECT SUM(Amount) 
  FROM FactFinance 
    INNER JOIN DimDate ON FactFinance.DateKey = DimDate.DateKey
  WHERE DimDate.[Date] <= DD.[Date]
) AS Amount 
FROM FactFinance FA 
  INNER JOIN DimDate DD ON FA.DateKey = DD.DateKey
WHERE DD.Date <= '09 Aug 2019' -- your max date to show in result
GROUP BY DD.Date
```

Another solution using [`SUM (...) OVER (...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql):

```
SELECT DD.[Date], SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER (ORDER BY DD.[Date]) AS Amount
FROM FactFinance FA INNER JOIN DimDate DD ON FA.DateKey = DD.DateKey
WHERE DD.[Date] <= '09 Aug 2019' -- your max date to show in result
GROUP BY DD.[Date]
```

You can put the queries above into a sub-select to exclude the rows with amount of 0 or lower:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DD.[Date], SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER (ORDER BY DD.[Date]) AS Amount
  FROM FactFinance FA INNER JOIN DimDate DD ON FA.DateKey = DD.DateKey
  WHERE DD.[Date] <= '09 Aug 2019' -- your max date to show in result
  GROUP BY DD.[Date]
) tSumAmount
WHERE tSumAmount.Amount > 0
```

Comment: That doesn't give the correct result @Sebastian Brosch, due to the <=

Comment: @Philip - Updated the answer using a sub-select.

Comment: Thanks, you've removed the having sum() though?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
select CONVERT(date, DD.Date) as Date, sum(Amount) as Amount from FactFinance FA
Inner Join DimDate DD on 
FA.DateKey = DD.DateKey
where DD.Date in('09 Aug 2019', '08 Aug 2019')
group by CONVERT(date, DD.Date)
having sum(Amount) >0
```

Comment: Note the <= with the Date Criteria, that wouldn't work.

Comment: Agree, but query should return "total by day"

Comment: That's right, which includes <= as part of the total by day.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CAST('09 Aug 2019' AS DATETIME) FinanceDate, sum(Amount)
from 
(
select sum(Amount) as Amount from FactFinance FA
Inner Join DimDate DD on 
FA.DateKey = DD.DateKey
where DD.Date <= '09 Aug 2019'
group by OccKey
having sum(Amount) >0
) a

UNION 

select CAST('08 Aug 2019' AS DATETIME) FinanceDate,sum(Amount)
from 
(
select sum(Amount) as Amount from FactFinance FA
Inner Join DimDate DD on 
FA.DateKey = DD.DateKey
where DD.Date <= '08 Aug 2019'
group by OccKey
having sum(Amount) >0
) a
```